# Difference on ArgumentCaptor between Mockito v1 and v2

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am currently upgrading the unit tests of a legacy project from Mockito v1 to Mockito v2.

In one of the unit test, I have the following code:

```
Listener listener = new Listener();
Alert alert = new Alert (listener);
alert.action(); // action calls 5 times the "notify" method on "listener"

ArgumentCaptor<Mess> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Mess.class);
verify(listener, times(5)).notify(argument.capture());
List<Mess> list_mess = argument.getAllValues(); // A

// The test checks list_mess and does some stuff on "alert"

alert.action(); // action calls 5 times the "notify" method on "listener"

argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Mess.class);
verify(listener, times(10)).notify(argument.capture());
list_mess = argument.getAllValues(); // B
```

Both "verify" are OK. But since I have been working with Mockito v2, list_mess has a different value:

- In mockito v1: at line A, the size of list_mess is 5 elements and is 10 elements at line B
- In mockito v2: at line A, the size of list_mess is 5 elements and is 5 elements at line B. The first 5 elements have been removed. Then the unit test fails because the next part of the code expects a list of size 10.

Does someone have an explanation of this behavior ? I didn't find anything on the Mockito wiki on this point. According to the javadoc of the "capture" method, the list_mess size should still be 10:

> Use it to capture the argument. This method **must be used inside of verification**.
>
> Internally, this method registers a special implementation of an {@link ArgumentMatcher}.
>
> This argument matcher stores the argument value so that you can use it later to perform assertions.

Comment: Why would the argument capture more than 5 elements if `Listener#notify` is only called 5 times? If `Listener#notify` is actually called 10 times, are the values in the list the argument the first 5 times the method is called, or the second 5 times, or some other combination?

Comment: Listener#notify is called 10 times (once for each alert#action)
The argument in the list are the 5 of the second call.
However I just had an answer from the Mockito team, it's actually a known bug of the v2

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a known bug by the Mockito team: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/819